# Simplifying C# line with loop or otherwise

Tags: c#, loops

sorry for dumb question, is there anyway to simplify this line with a loop, so i can perform it N times whilst increasing credit1 and grade1 each time?

```
    totalpoints = totalpointcalc(totalpoints, credit1.Text, grade1.Text);
            totalpoints = totalpointcalc(totalpoints, credit2.Text, grade2.Text);
            totalpoints = totalpointcalc(totalpoints, credit3.Text, grade3.Text);
```

Thanks if you can shed some insight :)

Comment: One question - what's the value in putting this (very readable and understandable) code into a loop? That is, what problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I am repeating that line 30 times and it would be a lot easier should I wish to change any aspect of it.

Comment: @LucasHolmes - It would be best to somehow get your credit and grade fields into respective Lists. Depending on your situation you may have to do this manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, any time you have variables named `var1`, `var2`, ... `varN`, you should probably be using an array (or list) instead.

Create an array to store your `credit` and `grade` controls, then loop through those arrays:

```
var credit = new[] { credit1, credit2, credit3 };
var grade = new[] { grade1, grade2, grade3 };

...

for(var i = 0; i < credit.Length; i++)
{
    totalpoints = totalpointcalc(totalpoints, credit[i].Text, grade[i].Text);
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on here, can you explain it a bit further? I apologise for not being quite fluent with coding.

Comment: @LucasHolmes What part are you confused about? The first part where I am creating the arrays or the second part where I'm looping through them?

Comment: @LucasHolmes - In a nutshell, he is creating 2 arrays, then looping through them by their index ([i]) and updating `totalpoints` each time through the collection.  BTW, +1.

Comment: @LucasHolmes Okay, `var` creates an implicitly typed variable, and the `new[] { ... }` is an implicit array initializer. I had to do this because it's not clear from your code what types you're controls are. Most likely you'd want to replace this with something like `TextBox[] credit = new TextBox[] { ... }` (or whatever control type you're using).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with an anonymous type:

```
var creditGrades = new[]
{
    new { credit = credit1.Text, grade = grade1.Text },
    new { credit = credit2.Text, grade = grade2.Text },
    new { credit = credit3.Text, grade = grade3.Text }
};
var total = creditGrades.Aggregate(0, (i, x) =>
                totalpointcalc(i, x.credit, x.grade));
```